# can we join with the same table we are creating in sql?

Tags: sql, sas

I'm wondering if it is possible to join the same table we are creating without having to copy the whole table code after the join.

For example:

```
create table tableC as
select * 
from (
    select *, min(a) as minA 
     from tableB
     group by id) as tb0 
) 
join (select *, min(a) as minA 
    from tableB
    where min(a) = 1) as tb1
on tb1.id = tb0.id;
```

In this example the join in not necessary, but still, in some case it is. 
My question is can we use the table in the first block code to perform the join without having to copy the entire code after the join?

to be more precise can we do something like

```
create table tableC as
select * 
from (
    select *, min(a) as minA 
     from tableB
     group by id) as tb0 
) 
join (select *
    from **tb0**
    where **minA** = 1) as tb1
on tb1.id = tb0.id;
```

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. You create `tableC` but you are selecting from `tableB`. That's perfectly fine.

Comment: I want to use the table tb0 to perform the join wihtout having to make the tb0 again. I'll modify my code a little bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the clean and easy way is to create a view:

```
proc sql noprint;
    create view myView as
    select *, min(a) as minA 
    from tableB
    group by id;
quit;

proc sql noprint;
    select *
    from myView as tb0
    join
    (
        select *
        from myView
        where minA=1
    ) as tb1
    on tb1.id=tb2.id;
quit;
```

It works (if i did not make a typo), it prevents code duplication and it looks cleaner. (the latter being a matter of personal opinion of course)

I wonder though what scenario you imagine where this particular join is useful.

Comment: I expected something else but the view is a quite an interesting alternative. To answer your question, I have a lot of variables to create and i need these variables to make up other variables. It save me from having to make more table than i need to.  Many thanks

Comment: you can do functions on variables you are creating in the same step as long as the aggregation level is the same.  for example `create table test as select date, sales, price, sales*price as revenue, calculated revenue/cost as newvar from source;`

Comment: @DJJ In SAS this is definitely the way to go, if you really have to do this.  From your use case example it doesn't sound like this should be needed either, but you'd have to explain further.

Answer (score 1):

In SAS, you cannot directly perform that function.  In TSQL that would be performed with a `with` block, but SAS does not (currently) support that.  That would look roughly like:

```
with tb0 as (
    select *, min(a) as minA 
     from tableB
     group by id)
select * from tb0 
 inner join
 (select 1 from tb0 where min(something)) tb1
  on tb0.id=tb1.id;
```